# Please enable JavaScript to continue using this application. - ng serve

Tags: javascript, angular, server-side-rendering

I have an angular app running V8, while i inspect the response to initial request is `Please enable JavaScript to continue using this application.` rendered in html document. Post of the initial request everything works fine(the app works as expected). I am trying to understand why am i getting the issue - if js wasn't enabled the app wouldn't work.

[image]

The image is from chrome console preview of initial request.

Comment: Do I understand correctly? *If you dig into the internals* of your app you see that message? It doesn't actually show up to the end user in the normal case? Then I don't see the issue: This is basically saying "I look at the source code and there's some error message strings there, how do I fix those?"

Comment: all i do is `ng serve` app - then go to console - i hit a path say `localhost:4200/foo` then i get the message in network tab - for this initial page request(foo) which comes under document category

Comment: Yes, **the network tab** which shows you stuff that's transferred between the server and the client but not necessarily displayed. You will see **all** of your client-side code there, no matter if it's being executed or not. I don't understand why this is a problem. Please explain how this negatively impacts *anything*?

Comment: @TheViralGriffin Did you manage to fix this problem in your app ? If yes, could you please share how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The image is from chrome console preview of initial request.

Because the Chrome Console preview doesn't download and execute all the JavaScript that would replace that message (and you *have* that message in the HTML document instead of using server side rendering which would provide better food for search engines and make [a more robust application](https://kryogenix.org/code/browser/everyonehasjs.html)).